# How can I debug a crash on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, developer-tools

I have a webpage that, when opened on iOS, the page crashes.

This is the URL: https://app.singular.live/output/2duBtIBClIAcU5st0SFT3F/Output

Safari first shows a message at the top of the page
*"This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred"*

And then after a few seconds, Safari shows a message *"A problem repeatedly occurred on [url]"*

I tried to debug this, by connecting my iPhone on opening the dev tools in Safari on my Mac. The problem is that once the webpage crashes, the dev tools console closes and therefore I can't use it to debug the issue.

I screen captured the console window, so I could check the console messages after it closed, and I saw there were no errors thrown when the page crashed.

Does anyone know a way of either **keeping the console window open** when the page crashes or **a different method** that I can use to debug the issue?

Running the page in the Xcode simulator doesn't crash, so can't use that to debug the issue either

Comment: i think the url you shared is live steam,Right?

Comment: No, it just html, js, and css

Comment: Was an answer to this ever identified? I am running in to a similar issue when working with audio files on mobile.

Comment: @BrianEllis no, never found a good way of debugging ios safari crashes :(